# Displaying UItableViewController inside UIPopoverController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I am dispalying a UITableViewController inside a UIPopoverController. Everything works fine expect that the size of the TableViewController is very large even thought there are only 3-4 cells. How can I make it so the popover controller's height is exactly the same as tableview's height?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UIPopoverController`'s method `- (void)setPopoverContentSize:(CGSize)size animated:(BOOL)animated` or use the property on `UIViewController` `@property(nonatomic, readwrite) CGSize contentSizeForViewInPopover` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `contentSizeForViewInPopover` of your `UITableViewController` like this:

```
- (CGSize)contentSizeForViewInPopover {
    // Currently no way to obtain the width dynamically before viewWillAppear.
    CGFloat width = 200.0; 
    CGRect rect = [self.tableView rectForSection:[self.tableView numberOfSections] - 1];
    CGFloat height = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);
    return (CGSize){width, height};
}
```